# Coverage not considering codes called from resource urls when using Flask

Tags: python, code-coverage

Python coverage is not considering codes that have been executed via resource urls.

**Example:**

I have resource url api.add_resource(Register, '/register') in server.py file. The /register url points to register method in user.py file. Test case that triggers /register successfully passes. However, code coverage for user.py is showing as 0%. How can we make coverage consider such methods called from api resource urls.